# How would I efficiently toggle different divs using an h tag?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am attempting to show a certain div when the relative li is selected. If any other divs are showing, I need to hide that one and only display the new one. There 1000% is a way more efficient way to do this then creating many useStates.

```
import {useState} from 'react'
import './dope.css'
export const PageContent = () => {
    const [one, setOne] = useState('false')
    const [two, setTwo] = useState('false')

    function toggle1(){
        set1(!1)
    }

    function toggle2(){
        set2(!2)

    }

    return (
        <section>
            <div className='middle_wrapper'>
                <div className='left_menu_wrapper'>
                    <nav className='nav_black'>
                        <li><a href='#!' onClick={toggle1}>1</a></li>
                        <li><a href='#!' onClick={toggle2}>2</a></li>
                        <li><a href='#!'>3</a></li>
                        <li><a href='#!'>4</a></li>
                        <li><a href='#!'>5</a></li>
                        <li><a href='#!'>6</a></li>
                        <li><a href='#!'>7</a></li>
                        <li><a href='#!'>8</a></li>
                        <li><a href='#!'>9</a></li>
                        <li className='no_border'><a href='/'>10</a></li>
                    </nav>
                </div>
                <div className='right_content'>
                    <section className='full_page'>
                        <div id='new_res' className={one? 'inactive' : 'active'}>
                            <h1>This is a 1 test</h1>
                        </div>
                        <div id='all_res' className={two? 'inactive' : 'active'}>
                            <h1>This is a 2 test</h1>
                        </div>
                    </section>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    )
}
---- From dope.css ----
.active {
    display: block;
}
.inactive {
    display: none;
}
--------
```

https://gyazo.com/1838ccf473832a00f341f4366b97b670

Like above, I would like to make this more efficient, it's probably something very simple that I am overlooking because I am tired and need sleep. I think I could simply just toggle the div's using href='#new_res' but how would I keep it hidden if it's not in use?

Any help would be appreciated, I know this is something simple and I by time someone answers, I may have found the solution. If not, thank you for helping!

Answer (score 0):

If possible, it would be more efficient to simply use a [checkbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/checkbox).

However, if you have to use React state for flexibility, you could make a state with an array instead:

```js
const [checkedArray, setCheckedArray] = useState([])
```

Whenever there is a new div to check toggle state, push a `false` into the array, when it is clicked, turn it to be true:

```js
// Example

// Adding new state
setCheckedArray((current)=>[...current,false])

// Mutating 3rd item's state
setCheckedArray((current)=>{  
    const newArray = [...current];
    newArray[3] = true;
    return newArray
})

// Getting the info of the 3rd item of the array
const stateOfThirdItem = checkedArray[3]
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a state to store all the components and their visibility flag. This will allow you to loop through them to dynamically render the anchors (and their `onClick` event) and also show them in the DOM.

https://codesandbox.io/s/so-71716290-bdsp9w?file=/src/PageContent.js